# Как сделать фильтр по букве алфавита?

Tags: javascript

Есть [вот такой "скрипт"](http://codepen.io/team/lincolnloop/pen/xbJqgR), фильтрующий список по нажатию на букву алфавита.

```
$('.AlphabetNav a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();  
    var $navItem = $(this),
        $contacts = $('.Contact');
    $contacts.show();
    if ($navItem.hasClass('active')) {
        $navItem.removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.AlphabetNav a').removeClass('active');
        $navItem.addClass('active');
        $.each($contacts, function(key, contact) {
            var $contact = $(contact),
                $contactName = $contact.find('.Contact-name'),
                $nameArr = $contactName.text().split(' ');
            console.log($nameArr[0].split('')[0].toLowerCase());
            if ($nameArr[0].split('')[0].toLowerCase() !== $navItem.text().toLowerCase()) {
                $contact.hide();
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Хочется сделать его на чистом JavaScript, но с некоторыми изменениями. С сервера приходит JSON на разных языках, поэтому список алфавитных букв тоже, соответственно, может быть разным. Каков алгоритм создания скрипта?

1. Сортируем массив (`items`) `sort`-ом по алфавиту.
2. Берем `items.values().chartAt[0]`, делаем цикл по всем элементам массива и, если `chartAt[0]` `indexOf` в новом массиве, то пропускаем.
3. Дальше не знаю.

Comment: А чем вас jQuery не устраивает?

Comment: Хочется потом на angular это перевести. А там jQuery ни к чему. Да и вообще интересно

Comment: Если хочется - делайте, мы не против ;)

Comment: Спасибо,конечно, но ...

Answer (score 2):

Привет, Micro!

Вот набросал тебе Плункр такого списка. В AngularJS есть такое понятие как фильтр, который очень хорошо подходит в твоём случае. Я не стал писать загрузку информации с json, думаю, это не очень сложно, поэтому буквы и имена в данном примере хранятся в простых массивах.

Главное из всего примера -- это фильтр:

```
app.filter('NameFilter', function() {
return function(input, criteria) {
  var output = [];

  for (name of input)
    if (criteria === undefined || name.toLowerCase().charAt(0) === criteria)
      output.push(name);

  return output;
}
```

});

В контроллере мы просто будем хранить букву для фильтра (criteria), которую затем будем передавать в сам фильтр. В данном примере нет ничего сложного:

1. С помощью директивы ng-repeat пройдемся по всем именам и выведем их в section
2. Добавим к ng-repeat наш фильтр, который принимает на вход массив имен, а возвращает только нужные имена

И всё. Надеюсь, мой ответ поможет : )
Удачи!

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kwk38Z4yAZdDGHc3ZoT9)